# Python Cv2.cornerHarris count number of corners returned

Tags: python, python-2.7, feature-detection

I'm running a different corner and edge detection algorithms in order to compare them.
I'm trying to count the number of corners detected from `cv2.cornerHarris` algorithm but the result returned is an image.
Counting the non-black values of returned image is not accurate..

Any suggestions of how to count found corners? (if it is even possible)